# Quasilinear second order parabolic equation

Tags: riemannian-geometry, differential-equations

For the following parabolic equation
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
u_t&=\frac{u_{xx}}{1+u_x^2}-\frac{1}{u}\\
&u(x,0)=\cosh x+1.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
How to show that $u(0,t)\sim \sqrt{t}\log t, t \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: How do you know that $\lim_{t\to \infty} u(0,t)/\sqrt{t}\log t=1$?

Comment: @Alan From the point of view of mean curvature flow, I guess it's more reasonable that its growth rate is smaller than that on the right.It may not be right.

Comment: I guess you can do repeated limits, as in $\lim_{(x,t)\rightarrow (0,\infty)}u(x,t)/\sqrt{t}\log t$, and then if you knew that at $t\to \infty$ $u(x,t)$ approaches $\pm \infty$ then you could have used the PDE with L'hopital; but this is quite a messy computation.